# bash/zsh cd command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, zsh, osx-yosemite

I am missing my basic unix commands on Yosemite 10.10

Here is my path from `~/.zshrc`

```
export PATH="/Users/tims/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/shared/bin:/usr
```

I will check my `~/.bash_profile`

Very strange

Comment: I added the missing "

Comment: What makes it strange is that `cd` is not an executable command but a built-in for the shell (at least it is for `bash`). The PATH shouldn't matter. Does `pwd` work? And try, `alias` to make sure `cd` wasn't mapped to something else... Why does your subject include `bash` and `zsh`? Are you having the same problem with `bash`? Which shell are you actually running? (HINT: it can't be both at the same time. ;))

Comment: Yes 'pwd' works

$ type -a cd

cd is a shell builtin

cd is /usr/bin/cd

Comment: If it's @ `/usr/bin/cd` then it's not "built-in". In `bash` three is no `cd` command file. The shell just knows how to do `cd` internally, which is why I asked. Exactly what error message do you get when you try `cd`? And what do you see on `ls -l /usr/bin/cd`?

Comment: Please update your question to show the command you type and the output you get. Copy and paste it so we can be sure it's exact.

Comment: Is that a specific reason for `node.js` being tagged on this question?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ type -a cd

cd is a shell builtin

cd is /usr/bin/cd
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116955/where-is-cd-located

Comment: fixed cd... but 'ls' and 'sh'.  'sh' works alone, but not with an argument